# How to send a TextBox value to a variable in the parent form in C#?

Tags: c#, variables

I have an aboutBox control ("settings") that has a textBox in it. When the user presses the save button on this settings I want it to save the string from the textBox, pass it to a variable in the main form, close the settings box and then press a button in the main form.

How would this be done?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes it's possible . But what have you done so far ?

Comment: Trigger an event when the about box control is saving, and then handle that event on the main form (not about box). Make the about box information public so it is accessible from the main form.

Comment: Created the settingsbox, added the textbox, the save button that closes the settings box. I have an event setup on the main form that needs to be raised after the save button does everything I mentioned. I have tried the get set methods but didn't have success because most examples on the internet is to pass text from form1 to form2 and show form2, in my case it's kind of opposite.

Comment: Here's how i do it when everything is on a single form:
`public void dosomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//do something
}
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 dosomething(sender, e);
}`

I'm not able to figure out how the button from another form or in my case aboutbox could run this dosomething event.

I hope this clears up what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

this is a sample code on how you would do it, you can add an event handler for the save button when your main start or if you use VisualStudio, double click on the Save button from your designer and it will create the event handler for you, but to add it manually at the start of the form,

In your main form,

```
private void settingsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    settingsBox box = new settingsBox(); 
    DialogResult  result = box.ShowDialog(); 
    //* check if the result to see if you did not cancel the save.
    //* if the user clicked on save

    String textVar = box.GetMyAboutText();
}
```

This is in your settings form

```
    String textVar = null;  //* define global in your settingsBox;
    public settingsBox()//* constructor
   {
      settingForm.Click += new System.EventHandler(myAboutSaveButton_Click);
   }

//*add the myAboutSaveButton_Click to handle the event 

    private String myAboutCtlSaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      textVar = myTextBox.Text;
      myAboutCtl.Dispose();

    }
       private void GetMyAboutText()
       {
          return textVar;
       }
```

Comment: I have that done but now how I pass this textVar to my mainForm?

Comment: I am assuming the myAboutCtlSaveButton_Click is in your mainForm, you can either have the textVar as a global variable or you can a add amethod in your mainForm to pass it, let me edit the answer to do the later,

Comment: The save button is on the settings form. The button is supposed to do all the actions and then close the settings form.

Comment: You must be start your settings form from the main form, would you post the code that starts your settings form, I will modify and add to it so that you can understand how pass the text field value back to the main form.  You basically will change the method SetMyAboutText to GetMyAboutText and call it from the main form

Comment: private void settingsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            settingsBox box = new settingsBox();
            box.ShowDialog();
        }

Comment: please see my updated answer, hope that works for you

Answer (score 1):

A solution using public methods. I have used controls with default names, see the comments for what these controls are related to.

Your `Main.cs` form :

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Mainform : Form
    {
        public Mainform()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new About(this).ShowDialog(); // pass main form to about form and show it a showdialog
        }

        // Public textbox updating method 
        public void textupdatert(string input)
        {
            textBox1.Text = input; // textBox1 is the textbox we need to update in Main form
        }
    }
}
```

Your `About.cs` form :

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class About : Form
    {
       private Mainform mymainform; // Holds main form instance

       // Contructor is updated to take the instance of Main Form
       public About(Mainform mainform)
       {
         InitializeComponent();
         mymainform = mainform;
       }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mymainform.textupdatert(textBox1.Text); // Update Parent form's'textBox1

            this.Close(); // Close about form and Exit 
        }

    }
}
```

This should work :)

Comment: Two errors:
Error 2 'WindowsFormsApplication6.About' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments 





Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication6.Form1.textupdatert(string)'

Comment: You need to update About form's Constructor part as given in my example. You need to accept main form's instance there.. " public About(Mainform mainform)" in my code.. And should call method on passed instance of Main form .! .. that should solve it :)

Comment: Also  textupdater() method is defined for the passed instance of main.. So in my code it's done as mymainform.textupdatert(yourtext);

Answer (score 0):

Add a property in FormSettings to return the TextBox value.

```
public string SomeText
{
    get { return textBox1.Text; }
}
```

Also, set the **DialogResult = OK** property to the *Apply* button, it will close the form dialog after press the button.

Usage:

```
using (var form = new FormSettings())
{
    if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var text = form.SomeText;
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below:

```
string txtBoxVal=TextBox.txt;
you can pass the textbox value using parameterized constructor of parent form.

call the parameterized constructor of parent form like

parentForm pf=new ParentForm(txtBoxVal)

In the parent form write a constructor as below:

string val; //globalVariable in the parent class
public ParentForm(string txtVal){
val=txtVal; // textbox value is assigned to val that you can use as your needs                 // in the class
}
```

Hope this helps, Thanks

Answer (score -1):

First thought is to create an event in the form where you press the save button and raise this event when this button is clicked. You can listen to this event from your parent form and perform needed actions from there

Comment: The event is created but how do I start the event form main form when the button is click from the settings form?