# Can Pass Value Form1 to Form2 but not from Form2 to Form1

Tags: c#, forms

I have two forms. Form1 and Form2. I can pass the value of ((Button)Sender).text from Form1  to the listbox of form2. But other way around when i try to pass ((Button)sender).text from form2 to form1 it gives error:
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter

Any Idea?
Thanks...

Form1 (Parent Form)

```
Public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach (Control butt in this.Controls)
    {
        if (butt is Button)
        {
            ((Button)butt).Click += Form1_Click;
        }
    }
}

public void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2= new Form2(((Button)sender).Text);
    form2.show();
}
```

Form2 (Child Form)

```
Public Form2(string valuefromform1)
{ 
    listbox1.items.add(valuefromform1);
}
```

But the following doesn't work

Form2 (Parent Form)

```
Public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach (Control butt in groupBox2.Controls)
    {
        if (butt is Button)
        {
            ((Button)butt).Click += Form2_Click;
        }
    }
}

public void Form2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1= new Form1(((Button)sender).Text);
    form1.show();
}
```

Form1 (Child Form)

```
Public Form1(string valuefromform2)
{ 
    listbox1.items.add(valuefromform2);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a TextBox value to a variable in the parent form in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621379/how-to-send-a-textbox-value-to-a-variable-in-the-parent-form-in-c)

Comment: Sorry i couldnt undertand that... can u explain here thanks

Comment: You are creating instance of each form in another. So, please clarify the question. Which is your child form Form1 or Form2 ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Form1 is parent form, Form2 is child form in first case where it works.